# Prints decreased days left with each List of date

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, console-application

I have a solution that does two things;

- Prints list of dates from today's date to a specific date (just fridays).
- Displays days left from today's date to the date I hard-coded

Right now my solution displays both date and current format:

```
Friday, March 26, 2021
Friday, April 2, 2021
Friday, April 9, 2021
Friday, April 16, 2021
Friday, April 23, 2021
Friday, April 30, 2021
Friday, May 7, 2021
Friday, May 14, 2021
Friday, May 21, 2021
Friday, May 28, 2021
Friday, June 4, 2021
Friday, June 11, 2021
Friday, June 18, 2021
Friday, June 25, 2021
Friday, July 2, 2021
Friday, July 9, 2021
Friday, July 16, 2021
Friday, July 23, 2021
Friday, July 30, 2021
Friday, August 6, 2021
Friday, August 13, 2021
Days left: 141
```

**But I want** to show in this format;

```
Friday, March 26, 2021 (days left - 141)
Friday, April 2, 2021 (days left - 134)
Friday, April 9, 2021 (days left - 127)
Friday, April 16, 2021 (days left - 120)
Friday, April 23, 2021 (days left - 113)
Friday, April 30, 2021 (days left - 106)
Friday, May 7, 2021 (days left - 99)
Friday, May 14, 2021 (days left - 92)
Friday, May 21, 2021 (days left - 85)
Friday, May 28, 2021 (days left - 78)
Friday, June 4, 2021 (days left - 71)
Friday, June 11, 2021 (days left - 64)
Friday, June 18, 2021 (days left - 57)
Friday, June 25, 2021 (days left - 50)
Friday, July 2, 2021 (days left - 43)
Friday, July 9, 2021 (days left - 36)
Friday, July 16, 2021 (days left - 29)
Friday, July 23, 2021 (days left - 22)
Friday, July 30, 2021 (days left - 15)
Friday, August 6, 2021 (days left - 8)
Friday, August 13, 2021 (days left - 1)
```

Here is my solution;

```
static void Main()
{
    var dates = new List<DateTime>();

    DateTime from = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime dateOnlyStart = from.Date;

    DateTime to = new DateTime(2021, 08, 14);
    DateTime dateOnlyEnd = to.Date;

    double dayLeft = to.Subtract(dateOnlyStart).TotalDays;

    //var to = DateTime.Today.AddDays(14); 

    for (var dt = dateOnlyStart; dt <= dateOnlyEnd; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
    {
        dates.Add(dt);
    }

    var allFridays = dates.Where(x => (int)x.DayOfWeek == 5);

    foreach (var date in allFridays)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("D"));
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Days left: {dayLeft}");

    //Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allFridays)} {Environment.NewLine} Days left: {dayLeft}");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Please tell me how to do this without omitting LINQ query, thanks in advance

Comment: does this answer your question? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: no @kshkarin I don't want to change the date format, I just want to display days left with each list of date in bracket, as i shown in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include remaining days computation in console output in a loop:

```
foreach (var date in allFridays)
{
    Console.WriteLine($@"{date.ToString("D")} (days left - {to.Subtract(date).TotalDays})");
}
```

Comment: your answer solve my problem but its shows the wrong days now you can check from here [link](https://ibb.co/KGndgZ8) I know something went wrong with my code, but where ?

Comment: which days are wrong and what output you expect instead?

Comment: please check my question, under "But I want to show in this format" that output I expected, I know its an entirely different question, but can you please tell me the solution?

Comment: @Zong, I was a bit confused by different data variables. I changed the math, see my edit

Comment: Thank you so much @ASh, stay blessed :)